# How to position a section title to float right in a card

Tags: css

> **I want to position my card title to the top right end like this image below...**

[image]

> **To my own (image Below)...**

[image]

> This is my HTML card code

```
<section class="features-main my-2">
    <h2 class="md text-center my-2">Our Menu</h2>
    <div class="container grid grid-3">
        <div class="card flex">
            <div>
                <button class="flex">chicken</button>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti amet, molestias accusantium minima
            excepturi illo asperiores placeat modi tempore debitis nisi, culpa ipsa saepe totam </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card flex">
            <div>
                <button>chicken</button>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, laboriosam.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card flex">
            <div>
                <button>chicken</button>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, laboriosam.</p>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</section>
```

> And my CSS file...

```
    .container {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.grid-3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }
  .my-2 {
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }

  .md {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
  .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .card {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0,0,0, 0.5);
}

.features-main .grid {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

NB: I'm not using Bootstrap or any library.
And I also want to make the first two cards position equally when in tablet mode.

> this is the media queries... what am I not doing correctly

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .features-main .grid > *:first-child {
        grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    }
    .features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr
    }
    .features-main .grid > *:last-child {
        grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    }
}

/*  Mobile  */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .grid,
    .features-main .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    }

    .features-main .grid > *:first-child,
    .features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2),
    .features-main .grid > *:last-child {
            grid-column: 1;
    }
}
```

[image: Tablet mode view]

Comment: Absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-direction:column` on your `.flex` class and then align the first div's contents to the right.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex>div {
  text-align: right;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.my-2 {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.md {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.features-main .grid {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="features-main my-2">
  <h2 class="md text-center my-2">Our Menu</h2>
  <div class="container grid grid-3">
    <div class="card flex">
      <div>
        <button>chicken</button>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti amet, molestias accusantium minima excepturi illo asperiores placeat modi tempore debitis nisi, culpa ipsa saepe totam </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card flex">
      <div>
        <button>chicken</button>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, laboriosam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card flex">
      <div>
        <button>chicken</button>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, laboriosam.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```